# Video on blog has been removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, videos

I was looking the blog [Now Earn Valuable Flair!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/nowearn-valuable-flair/). But the video in that blog has been removed.

[image]

It's request to authorized person of the blog to add the video on this blog.

Comment: You should ask jeff about it

Comment: @BhuvanRikka but How?

Comment: Try his blog..[Coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/)

Comment: I know which video it was, so I'll try to find a replacement for it tomorrow.

Comment: @AnnaLear Okay. Is this correct way to request about blogs? (By asking a question on Meta)

Comment: @hims056 Yes, this is fine. :)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5YClmS3umk