# Vote to close own question

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close

Well, I've just done this out of curiosity, but since a user is not allowed to upvote/downvote his questions/answers, is there any specific reason behind allowing him to vote for close his own question?

Comment: If they can't delete due to upvoted answers it but realise it's unsuitable/a duplicate why not allow the OP to help the community remove the problematic question

Comment: You can realize it after asking it is a dublicate of off-topic, so you can vote to close the question.

Comment: What exactly `bug` and `hidden-feature` are you talking about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not? If the user has realized that it is a dupe or off topic, helping to close it seems like a sensible thing. I've done this plenty of times, generally with dupes.

For example:

- [Centralised location to view closevotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128222/centralised-location-to-view-closevotes)
- ["1 more comment" when you submit a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127513/1-more-comment-when-you-submit-a-comment)
- [Public beta--smoothly transition the privilege rep-requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132230/public-beta-smoothly-transition-the-privilege-rep-requirements)
- [Supercollider realtime updates incomplete-ish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128053/supercollider-realtime-updates-incomplete-ish)

and more

Comment: Yup. Few more examples [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158786/187824), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148413/187824), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148377/187824) [etc..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146618/187824)

Answer (score 5):

Consider

1. User A posted a question
2. He got a good answer.
3. User A finds another question which this one is a duplicate of also has an answer which 
   does accomplishes the task in another way.
4. He know both answers are good and useful to community, but there is a chance that only one will be searched and found by other people (since many of them stop searching when they get the answer). So he wanted to put those answers into one place.
5. He can vote to close, saying this question is a duplicate.

Good samaritan. Ok, comparing this with upvoting/downvoting his own questions/answers.

- **upvoting**: No way it helps the community, if people starts to prop up himself to get attention
- **downvoting**: If he is good enough to know that his post is not wanted here, he shouldn't have posted it.

That is my take... There might be many other reasons.