# Questions are placed 'on hold' but we offer the chance to 'close,' not 'hold'

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Given that we now place questions 'on hold,' rather than closing them, it seems odd that the OP is, for their own question, offered the chance to 'close,' rather than 'hold,' their question.

[image]

<sub>(Almost certainly irrelevant, but screenshot taken from my own question: "[How to colour the list-style-type auto-generated numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725741/how-to-colour-the-list-style-type-auto-generated-numbers)")</sub>

Admittedly this may well make sense from a UI perspective, since the OP should have greater control over their own questions and be able to 'close' their question. However, if this is the intent there are two problems I have with the choice:

1. Closure by the OP implies a permanent action, which is duplicated by the option to 'delete,' a *temporary* action (to allow for editing, clarification and general improvements) would be better served with the temporary-sounding 'hold' option.
2. Inconsistency between the actions taken by other users and those available to the OP.

Ideally, I'd prefer the 'close' option in the options available to the OP to become 'hold,' if only for consistency.

---

Edited to add that on reflection -and having read Ilmari's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230524/questions-are-placed-on-hold-but-we-offer-the-chance-to-close-not-hold#comment757281_230524) and [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230526/130770)- I would prefer for the 'close' option to be removed entirely for the OP on their own questions, as I don't see what purpose is met by closing a question for the OP that isn't met by deletion, on the assumption they've decided they don't want further answers/interaction.

Comment: On hold is simply a label that a closed question gets for the first few days. It is there to encourage the asker to edit and improve the question by showing a status that is less "final" than "closed".

Comment: Deletion isn't permanent either, btw.

Comment: @Ilmari: that's a point I hadn't considered, actually; the duplication is (arguably/apparently) redundant.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, I'd now like to vote to close the question, but I can't figure out a valid reason from those available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On hold" is *the exact same thing* as "closed." It is simply shown with a different wording for the first few days to look friendlier.

> a temporary action (to allow for editing, clarification and general improvements) would be better served with the temporary-sounding 'hold' option

Why does the question need to be closed for that to happen? "General improvements" should be made while the question is still open. A closed question means that it is unanswerable in some way, not that it is being improved. The purpose of closing a question is to prevent answers, not to "suspend" a question to make improvements.

> Inconsistency between the actions taken by other users and those available to the OP.

This "close" button is the exact same button that you get for others' questions at 3k rep. This is by no means specific to closing your own question - you should treat the close button on your own question the same as the close button on other posts.

Comment: They don't have to be 'closed for that to happen,' but I couldn't think of any other reason to have a second option. Which should've made me request the removal of the 'close'/'hold' options for the OP, I suppose.

Comment: @David "A second option"? What second option? Also, the close button is shown on your own post so that if you realize it should be closed (for example, as a duplicate) then you can. (Your close vote will apply just like any other user's.)

Comment: I phrased that badly, my apologies; I'd argue now (having read [Ilmari's comment to the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230524/questions-are-placed-on-hold-but-we-offer-the-chance-to-close-not-hold#comment757281_230524)) that there are two options available to the OP that duplicate the same functionality, the 'close' and 'delete' options; and I can't see a solid reason that there should be more than one. My previous comment referred to 'close' as the "second option."

Comment: @David Huh? How are closing and deleting the same thing? They have completely different functionalities.

Comment: So, what's the functional difference; and what would be the purpose of maintaining those differences?

Comment: @David The only thing closure does is prevent answers. You can still comment, vote, edit, and quite easily get the question reopened if you improve it. Closed questions are still completely visible on the site. Deletion completely removes a question from the site, unless a 10k user has a link to it, and it's much harder to get a question undeleted.

Comment: Indeed, but why would the OP *want* to close a question rather than delete a question? To remove a question from the site I'd delete it, if I wanted people to interact with it I'd leave it open (unclosed/undeleted); what benefit does closure offer the OP? We are, though, perhaps drifting a little far from the question. If it feels like I'm being argumentative, asinine or obtuse that really isn't my intent; but I feel like I'm missing something important from your viewpoint. Sorry.

Comment: @David Don't worry, you're like a businessman compared to some of the other users we see here. ;-) There could be many reasons for that, such as finding a duplicate but wanting to keep the question for future visitors searching on the site with a different wording. In fact, I've done this a few times. I'm pretty sure I've seen a meta post regarding closing your own question; I'm trying to find it now.

Comment: @David [Here's a related post.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163375/180276)

Comment: Thank you; do you feel like adding a summary of your arguments in favour of retaining both of the options (close/delete) to your answer (then I can accept it and remove the noise of this comment thread)? Though I have a horrible feeling I'll shortly make a feature-request to consolidate the 'close'/'delete' functionality and links for the OP's own questions (if it *can* be deleted it should be, if it *can't* be deleted it should be regarded as a close-vote, though this may become even more confusing).

Comment: I have to take a bit of issue with what seems to be an stance of anti-improvement of closed questions in your answer. "A closed question means that it is unanswerable in some way, not that it is being improved." If possible, we'd like it if closed questions would be improved to the point of justifying reopening. Preventing answers helps prevent the page from becoming an incoherent mess if the question is heavily edited.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the real problem is that the "close" option is shown to the OP in the first place (if they have the "cast close votes" privilege, that is).

Sure, it's consistent, in a way, to have the "close" option available and working the same way on all questions, including your own.  In practice, though, a user's own questions *are* a special case, and one that the current close-vote UI / functionality in no way accounts for.

Given that there's rarely any legitimate reason to vote to close your own question, I'd be willing to suggest that the option should simply be removed.  If you ever do feel that your post does need to be closed (as opposed to just deleted), you could always flag it and ask a mod to close it.

Comment: So if you find a duplicate of your own question, or someone else does, you'd have to bug a moderator just to close it? I myself have voted to close my own posts before.

Comment: "rarely" except when it's a duplicate case and just like Doorknob I've experienced that too.